# Choose dialog between 2 predefined paths

Tags: batch-file

I've two file paths (two *.exe files in predefined paths) and need a dialog to help me choose between choice A or choice B,
the output is launched after pressing "ok"

How can I archive this with a bat file?

I don't use windows most of the time and don't have coding experience with windows. But the first tip helped me to come up with this code :

```
set path_1="C:\Program Files\App1.exe"
set path_2="C:\Program Files\App2.exe"

CHOICE /C AB /M "choose [A] or [B]"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 start "%path_2%"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 start "%path_1%"
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Some tips?

Comment: I suggest the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command.

Comment: I'd advise that you never need to go to a web site, to learn how to use built-in Windows commands. Just open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your edited question code, the issue you now have, is that you have not read the usage information for the `Start` command. Currently it is treating the first doublequoted argument as the title, so to fix your issue, include a title yourself.

The code example below, uses an empty title:

```batch-file
Set "path_1=C:\Program Files\App1.exe"
Set "path_2=C:\Program Files\App2.exe"

C:\Windows\System32\choice.exe /C AB /N /M "Choose [A] or [B]"
If %ERRORLEVEL% Equ 2 (Start "" "%path_2%") Else Start "" "%path_1%"
```

To see the usage information for the `Start` command, open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?`, and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

Comment: @Jarold, the code I have posted, without any modification whatsoever, will start the executable `C:\Program Files\App2.exe`, if you enter the case insensitive alphabet character `B` at the prompt, and start the executable `C:\Program Files\App1.exe`, if you enter the case insensitive alphabet character `A` at the prompt. If you have anything except for the content I have provided, I am not supporting it, or asssisting you with it, under this specific answer.

Comment: Success! Thanks for your support, I forgot to remove a quote from a file path, because first i declared my variables outside quotes. I didn't get what title does but I'm very happy or code works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
set "path_1=C:\Program Files\App1.exe"
set "path_2=C:\Program Files\App2.exe"
```

Use `set "var1=data"` for setting values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. In comparisons, use `if "thing1" == "thing2" ...` to avoid problems caused by spaces in `thing1/2`.

Assigning quoted strings to variables make the variables hard to combine logically. Inserting quotes as needed is far simpler.

Your code would execute (eg) `start ""C:\Program Files\App1.exe""` Inner quotes from variable, outer from instruction. `start` would interpret this as : first quotes are window-title (optional, always first quoted string on line, best always specified, even if empty) Then perhaps object to `C:\Program` appearing directly after without separator, perhaps accept it but see `Files\App1.exe""` as arguments to `C:\Program`

Comment: I'm not much into windows so I can't do much of scientific explanations, I need just direct examples. Anyway, thanks